# Auth/User's public profile

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm a newbie on Laravel. Also, I'm not very good at PHP. So, I'm trying to create a public profile for the Auth users, But I'm not getting it how to do.

I used this on `routes.php`

```
Route::get('{username}', 'UserController@profile_public');
```

in `UserController.php`:

```
public function profile_public(){
    return view('profile', array('user' => Auth::user()) );
}
```

in my `profile.blade.php`:

```
@if (Auth::guest())
            <img src="/uploads/avatars/{{ Auth::user()->username }}/{{ Auth::user()->avatar }}" style="width:150px; height:150px; float:left; border-radius:50%; margin-right:25px;">
            <h2>{{ $user->name }}'s Profile</h2>
        @else
            <img src="/uploads/avatars/{{ Auth::user()->username }}/{{ Auth::user()->avatar }}" style="width:150px; height:150px; float:left; border-radius:50%; margin-right:25px;">
            <h2>{{ $user->name }}'s Profile</h2>
            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/profile" method="POST">
                <label>Update Profile Image</label>
                <input type="file" name="avatar">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                <input type="submit" class="pull-right btn btn-sm btn-primary">
            </form>
        @endif
```

I'm trying to show the `avatar` and `name` for now. But it's not working for me. I'm getting this error - `Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\bimbl\resources\views\profile.blade.php)`

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `Auth::user()` in your view when you already pass the user to the view as `$user`? Also, the result of `Auth::user()` will be null (i.e. non-object) if they are not logged in. You need to use `Auth::check()` before trying to use the user.

Comment: You need to fetch the user's details from the database instead of using `Auth::user()` which is for the currently logged in user.

Comment: I already said i'm newbie with the laravel. That is why i asked for help. And please read the title once again. I'm trying to create a public profile without any login. I'll just want to pass username in url and get the public details of that user.

Comment: whoever down voted the question, i'm sure he is newb then me! :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call `Auth::user()` to get guest details, it doesn't work like that. `Auth::user` is calling an authenticated user.

You're getting that error because the result of `Auth::user()` is `null` because no authentication has taken place. So you're trying to look for properties on a `null` value.

If you want to pull data for a guest user, you're better off just calling something like `User::where('username', 'myguestusername')->first()`, assuming that you are indeed using the `users` table.

It should go in your `UsersController`:

```
public function profile_public($username)
{
    $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();

    return view('profile')->with('username', $user);
}
```

Since your route is requesting `{username}` as a parameter, you must also ensure you pass it to your `profile_public` method as shown above. That way your call to `User` model knows what to look up.

Comment: Do you think its an answer to my problem? I'm not asking for only why I'm getting the error, I'm looking for a solution on how can i show user's info that I want to be public, like facebook profile (if you put anything public, eveyone sees them)

Comment: This community doesn't exist to just give you the answer. It requires you to do your best to look for the answer on your own and think about it, clearly none of which you have done. You won't get any more help until you read what we are saying. In the case however, I have given you the very obvious and easy answer.

Comment: You just answered and edited a couple of times. So, I guess this community is to help newbies. But I'm sure, whoever answer to a question, it is best if they read the question fully. And, yes, i did my try. Otherwise a newbie cannot even create what i created above! :P

Comment: It's to help people who listen to the ones that are trying to help them.

Comment: btw, can you tell me where or how to use `User::where('username', 'myguestusername')->first()`  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120250/discussion-between-xahed-kamal-and-jared-eitnier).